# Java Servlets. Сайт localhost выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз. Не понимаю почему

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

```
public class RestaurantsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestaurantsServlet.class);

    private RestaurantRepository restaurantRepository;
    private VoteRepository voteRepository;


    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        restaurantRepository = new InMemoryRestaurantRepositoryImpl();
        voteRepository = new InMemoryVoteRepositoryImpl();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        LOG.debug("forward to restaurants");

        request.setAttribute("restaurant", restaurantRepository.getAll());
        //request.getRequestDispatcher("restaurants.jsp").forward(request, response);
        response.sendRedirect("restaurants");

    }

}
```

**restaurants.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin-left: 40px;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    td, th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    .name {
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .dish {
      font-weight: bold;

    }
  </style>
  <title>Restaurants</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
  <h2><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></h2>
  <p></p>
  <h2>Restaurants Rating</h2>
  <hr>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Menu</th>
      <th>Rating</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  <c:forEach items="${restaurant}" var="r">
  <jsp:useBean id="r" scope="page" type="com.systems.LunchVoting.model.Restaurant"/>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="name">${r.name}</span> <br>
            ${r.description}
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="dish">Dish - price</span> <br>
          Dish Description
        </td>
        <td>1023</td>
        <td>
          <a href="">Update Menu</a><br>
          <a href="">Delete Restaurant</a>
        </td>

    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
  </table>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>LunchVoting</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestaurantsServ</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.systems.LunchVoting.web.RestaurantsServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestaurantsServ</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restaurants</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UsersServ</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.systems.LunchVoting.web.UsersServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UsersServ</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/users</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: См. `response.sendRedirect("restaurants");` "restaurants" куда ведёт? В `RestaurantsServlet`. А там опять попадает `response.sendRedirect("restaurants");` а"restaurants" куда ведёт? В `RestaurantsServlet`. А там опять попадает `response.sendRedirect("restaurants");` а"restaurants" куда ведёт? В `RestaurantsServlet`. А там опять попадает `response.sendRedirect("restaurants");` а"restaurants" куда ведёт? В `RestaurantsServlet`. А там опять попадает `response.sendRedirect("restaurants");` Пришлось прекратить из-за  ограничения на количество буков. Надейюсь ясно что происходит.

Comment: спасибо за помощь.